# Concrete Rows of Id 2 with Id 1 IF Date is Same and All Row Names Should be different in SQL Server 2008R2 and

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have following Data in myRecords Table

```
Id     Date                 Name     Cash
1   11/25/2016 4:23.123     Ramesh  10000
2   11/25/2016 4:23.173     Suresh  15000
1   11/27/2016 5:23.320     Ramesh  30000
2   11/27/2016 5:23.670     Suresh  40000
```

and I want to create view So I can  get data in following Format

```
Id1 Date1               Name1   Cash1   Id2 Date2               Name2   Cash2
1   11/25/2016 4:23.123  Ramesh 10000   2   11/25/2016 4:23.173 Suresh  15000
1   11/27/2016 5:23.320  Ramesh 30000   2   11/27/2016 5:23.670 Suresh  40000
```

How can I do it.

Comment: this can be don a few ways but to get this right we would need to know how you intend on determining which row is related to eachother as names and ids do not match.  For example one could create a row_number() based on the datetime and then use a self join to join row_number to row_number + 1 but is that how the records should get paired?

Comment: depends on your data, the ids are 1 & 2 only or maybe to be 3, 4 ... etc ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are doing date and there will always only be 2 records per day you could convert to drop off the time and do a self join:

```
DECLARE @myRecords AS TABLE (Id INT, DATE DATETIME, Name VARCHAR(20), CASH INT)

INSERT INTO @myRecords VALUES (1,'11/25/2016 4:23','Ramesh',10000),(2,'11/25/2016 4:23','Suresh',15000)
,(1,'11/27/2016 5:23','Ramesh',30000),(2,'11/27/2016 4:23','Suresh',40000)

SELECT
    m1.Id as Id1
    ,m1.Date as Date1
    ,m1.Name as Name1
    ,m1.Cash as Cash1
    ,m2.Id as Id2
    ,m2.Date as Date2
    ,m2.Name as Name2
    ,m2.Cash as Cash2
FROM
    @myRecords m1
    LEFT JOIN @myRecords m2
    ON CAST(m1.DATE AS DATE) = CAST(m2.DATE AS DATE)
    AND m1.Id <> m2.Id
WHERE
    m1.Id = 1
```

Then you can also introduce `ROW_NUMBER()` to figure out whatever order you want then take all of the *ODD RowNumbers* and `SELF JOIN` to the *Even RowNumbers*:

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
       *
       ,RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Date) 
    FROM
       @myRecords
)

SELECT *
FROM
    cte c1
    LEFT JOIN cte c2
    ON c1.RowNum + 1 = c2.RowNum
WHERE
    c1.RowNum % 2 <> 0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot This helps me out.

Comment: One more Challenge, here I want to change column Names for If RowNum is Even i.e. Here You have made another columns if RowNum is even. So Now I want to change Column Names to be different. i.e. RowNum2, Id2, Date2, Name2, Cash2.

Comment: all you need to do is alias them.  I have updated my answer to show you how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

As long as your `Id` joining logic is unclear, this will help In this case but you will need to add `Id` Filter or additional Identity column and `row_number()` in future I guess.

```
SELECT
     T.*, TT.*
FROM
     [Table] AS T
        INNER JOIN
     [Table] AS TT
        ON T.Date = TT.Date
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Cross Apply` for the required result set.

```
 SELECT [ID],
           [DATE],
           [NAME],
           [CASH],
           B.*
    FROM   #TABLE1 A
           CROSS APPLY (SELECT ID     AS ID2,
                               [DATE] AS DATE2,
                               [NAME] AS NAME2,
                               [CASH] AS CASH2
                        FROM   #TABLE1 B
                        WHERE  A.ID < B.ID
                               AND CONVERT(DATE, A.DATE) = CONVERT(DATE, B.DATE))B
```

Answer (score 0):

This will also return the same result:

```
select a.id, a.date, a.name, a.cash, b.id as id2, b.date as date2, 
    b.name as name2, b.cash as cash2 
from myTable a
inner join myTable b on a.id+1 = b.id
    and cast(a.date as date) <> cast(b.date as date)
```